# How to generate database diagram or ER diagram automatically with pl/sql developer?

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

How to generate database diagram or ER diagram automatically with pl/sql developer?
I'm asking about pl/sql developer not sql developer.

Comment: You've mistaken SO for google.

Answer (score 3):

Diagram Window may be an option for you. You can create one from **File -> New -> Diagram Window** and then you "drag and drop" the objects you need from the Object Browser. You can select multiple objects at a time and then "drag and drop" them, but I don't know any better way of selecting the tables you need. Not very user friendly, but still useful.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, this is not possible with the PL/SQL developer.

Maybe there is another tool that can make a ERD from a Oracle DB.

Comment: Thx, I haven't found any solution with pl/sql developer either, I have used some online tools istead.

Comment: Could you (or anyone out there) provide some links?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is available in Oracle SQL Developer, available on both Mac and PC. Look at this article: https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/11/how-to-generate-an-erd-for-selected-tables-in-sql-developer/

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to this problem, going to try Oracle SQL Developer